# Change the button size to fit the text size

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

There is a button that is added to the subview. The button has a text which size can vary. Here's the button code:

```
let button: LinkButton = {
    let bt = LinkButton()
    bt.LinkString = link
    bt.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
    bt.setTitle("TEXT", for: UIControlState.normal)
    bt.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    bt.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    bt.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.07, green: 0.32, blue: 0.89, alpha: 1.0), for: UIControlState.normal)
    bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(linkOut), for: .touchUpInside)
    return bt
}()
```

The problem is that if the text is too large, the size of the button does not adjust to the size of the text and it starts to run into other subviews:
[image]

Constraints are specified and the button is located where necessary. The problem is only with the dimensions.

Constraints for the button:

```
contentView.addSubview(button)
button.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
```

in bottomAnchor the bottomAnchor of the previous element is stored in the subview output loop

[image]

Comment: Do you use auto layout ?

Comment: @Gihan Yes, I use auto layout

Comment: One reason could be you have not properly set the constraints for the button. Can you share your constraints ?

Comment: @Gihan I added this

Comment: From the looks of it , don't you think you need a topAnchor as well ?

Comment: The size of the button is adjusting to show all the text, since you have declared it as multiline. The problem more likely is that you have not constrained the next element's top to the button's bottom.

Comment: @Gihan topAnchor is the bottom of the previous item. The application grid is aligned as needed, but in calculating the height of the UICollectionView, an error appears in the texts with the button. And the only thing that can be calculated incorrectly is the button. Picture added

Comment: @MikeTaverne The button, like other text elements, is in a loop that displays the elements one by one, one after another, keeping its bottomAnchor in a variable, to which the next element clings topAnchor. The problem is that if the text of the button is too large, the indent of the button of the previous element is less and less, although the indent is set in constraints and is equal to 15